# Utilizing Console Interfaces for Hg, SVN or git

Tags: version-control, user-interface, console

I've been spending a lot of time utilizing [Mercurial](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/). On windows, I've been using [TortoiseHg](http://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/stable/) and on Linux and Mac OS X, I've been (forced) to use the console interface.

After spending time with the console utilities, I find (to my surprise) that I do like them.

But, most of my usage has been superficial. I've been doing basic clones, pulls and merges with the rare but occasional commit. I've not done any heavy lifting with it.

What I'm curious about is if *regular* users use the console interface of tools like Mercurial, SVN and/or git for real world, day-to-day development? Until now, I've never given the console program of SVN much thought -- I've always used [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/).

I realize that there is no *real* answer to this question (Hence, it's community wiki) but I thought other real-world insight would be beneficial. If others have successfully used these console programs, perhaps it's worth using them more.

So, do you use the console programs on a regular day-to-day basis or do you only use them when you need to?

*Note: I do realize that people use the console programs. It is ridiculous to think they are not used. This question is focused on day-to-day use for average developers for average development. Average being that you generally use GUI interfaces and/or you are developing  GUI applications.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I develop primary on OS X, frequently on Linux, and occasionally on Windows. The only place I *don't* use the console utilities is in Windows, where I'm not as familiar (and thus not as productive) with the console. On OS X and Linux, I exclusively use the command-line utilities for Git, Mercurial, and Subversion. I find the command-line utilities to be more powerful (especially in the case of Git), and I feel more "at home" with them.

I do use gitk and GitX (a gitk-like program for OS X) to visualize Git histories, but that's the only GUI tool I use.

Answer (score 1):

I use the svn binary regularly on Unix, doing "svn up", "svn diff", "svn commit", "svn ann", and "svn log" most of the time. I prefer the command line, because I have a shell window open in the source anyway (to run builds and tests), and along with file name completion, using the keyboard is faster than using the mouse for me.

Answer (score 0):

I use Mac and I love git to be used in command line.
I use the following utilities & tools to make productive & intuitive.

- [Git aware prompt](https://github.com/jimeh/git-aware-prompt) to show the currently checkout branch all the time
- [Iterm2](https://www.iterm2.com/) as a replacement for the default Mac terminal
- [Meld](https://yousseb.github.io/meld/) as git diff & mergetool

Both Iterm2 & Meld can be installed via homebrew (`brew cask install meld`)
My terminal screen looks like:[image]

[Source Tree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) is a must have GUI tool if you don't love CLI so much.